# Using an empty AngularStrap attribute with Slim

Tags: angularjs, slim, angular-strap

I'd like to use the Angularstrap styling for . However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the "bs-select" option in slim.

This is the format in normal html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectedIcon" 
 data-html="1" ng-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in icons" bs-select>
  Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

And this is what it would look like in slim:

```
button.btn.btn-default type="button" ng-model="selectedIcon" data-html="1" 
ng-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in icons" bs-select
  | Action
  span class="caret"
```

Because the bs-select attribute doesn't "=" something. It shows up as button text instead of creating a select dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

`<button bs-select>` is actually equivalent to `<button bs-select="bs-select">`, but `<button bs-select="">`would be fine as well.

To get this in slim, try the following:

```
button[bs-select]
```

or

```
button bs-select=""
```

### Reference:

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes

### Dealing with parenthesis from angular in slim

To mark attributes, different kinds of parenthesis are allowed by default: (), [], {} or none

It makes sense to remove curly brackets, because it collides with the angular syntax in:

```
h2 {{article.title}}
```

Here, slim will interpret `{article.title}` as an attribute and will afaik throw an error.

So better configure slim like this:

```
:attr_delims => {'(' => ')', '[' => ']'}, # removed '{' => '}' from default
```

Comment: I updated the link and added a part to deal with the probably next problem to follow.

Comment: how do we "configure slim like this"? Which file, where do we place that code? Does it also apply to using slim-rails gem, as well as slim gem, or slim via bower-rails?

Comment: The link was probably only temporarily not available. It works for me.

The configuration of slim depends on your setup. I used this within middleman. There configuration happens like this:

```ruby
# config.rb

# Slim configuration
set :slim, {
  :format  => :html5,
  :attr_delims => {'(' => ')', '[' => ']'}, # removed '{' => '}' from default
}
```